# Attempting .reverse() on a sorted dictionary, But getting 'None''

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I am trying to sort a dictionary loaded from the a file, however i am getting 'None' when sorting it in reverse, I have looked for possible solutions but cannot seem to find anything, It probably is something stupid but any help would be appreciated :)

(I used this as a attempt to sort in reverse:  [How to sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-by-value))

```
import operator
x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

and then someone in the comments said that using

```
sorted_x.reverse()
```

would return the sorted results but in biggest numbers first... however this is not the case....

Here is my code, i have tried to take out as much stuff as possible that is not necessary

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import operator
debug = True
quizanddifficulty = "Maths,Easy"
score = 3
uinputuname = "Kieron"

# Get current operating File Path
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(dir_path)
pathsplit = dir_path.split("\\")
newstring = ""
for string in pathsplit:
    newstring = newstring + str(string) + "\\\\"
print(newstring)
currentpath = newstring


split = quizanddifficulty.split(",") # Split Quiz Type and Difficulty (Quiz = split[0] and difficulty = split[1])
quizfiledifficulty = split[0] + split[1] + ".npy" # Set file extension for the doc
overall = currentpath + "QUIZDATA" + "\\\\" + quizfiledifficulty # Set overall file path (NEA\QUIZDATA\{Quiz}.npy)
try:
    # Load
    dictionary = np.load(overall).item()
    dictionary.update({score:uinputuname})
    np.save(overall, dictionary)

except OSError:
    # Save
    if debug:
        print(OSError)
        print("File does not already exist, Creating!")
    dictionary = {score:uinputuname}
    np.save(overall, dictionary)
print(dictionary)
sorted_x = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
print(sorted_x.reverse())
```

Comment: `list.reverse()` operates **in place** and returns `None`. Just add `reverse=True` to your `sorted()` call, or first call `list.reverse()` and *then* print the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse acts in-place

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
```

invoking reverse on a non-bound temporary object is useless ;). You need to bind it:

```
>>> b=sorted(a)
>>> b.reverse()
>>> b
[3, 2, 1]
```